# Passing dynamic control as argument to user defined method in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-controls

My problem is very straight forward. I am using asp.net with c#.

In my page I have many controls like `DropDownList`, `GridView`, `Repeater` etc.

And in some condition I want to reset the control as

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = null;
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

What I want , I like to build a common `Method` for resetting all the controls, like:

```
void SomeMethod(Template T)
{
    T.DataSource = null;
    T.DataBind();
}
```

Here the `T` can be any of the above mentioned `asp controls`.

I heard that this can be possible using `Template Type`, but I have no idea HOW!!!

So please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing how generic methods work in C#. I do not think generic methods apply here. You can read up on how (and when) to utilize them here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx

As for your particular case, it seems that most controls that support data binding are derived from [BaseDataBoundControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The simplest solution would be to create a method that accepts BaseDataBoundControl as a parameter like so:

```
void SomeMethod(BaseDataBoundControl control)
{
    control.DataSource = null;
    control.DataBind();
}
```

One exception that I see from your question is the [Repeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Because it doesn't inherit from BaseDataBoundControl I'd implement an overloaded method that accepts the Repeater class as a parameter.

```
void SomeMethod(Repeater control)
{
    control.DataSource = null;
    control.DataBind();
}
```

The result is two simple methods that have the same usage from elsewhere in your code, no matter if you operate on types derived from BaseDataBoundControl or a Repeater class.

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to find the common `class` or `interface` from that classes. From my little research it is [`DataBoundControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.databoundcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

After this you create a generic method (if you want to use templates) and put a constraint for inheritance, like below.

```
void SomeMethod<T>(T dataControl) where T : DataBoundControl
{
     T.DataSource = null;
     T.DataBind();
}
```

**Notes:**

1. Using [`DataBoundControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.databoundcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will work only for `DropDownList`, `GridView` and other that inherit from it. The `Repeater` inherit directly from `Control` class.
2. You can use this method as an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/bb383977.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You could do it as an extension method so all GridBoundControls have the method available to them:

```
internal static class ExtenstionMethods
{
    internal static void ClearData( this DataBoundControl control )
    {
        control.DataSource = null;
        control.DataBind();
    }
}
```

You can then call it like:

```
grdReports.ClearData();
ddlAnswers.ClearData();
etc.
```

Comment: Nice Answer. +1 Also, you can also add how OP can easily invoke this method :)